# Email Composer with Attachments iOS Phonegap

Tags: ios, email, cordova, attachment

I am trying to I am trying to attach a PDF through the `emailcomposerwithattachment` plugin founds [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposerWithAttachments).

The problem is when the email composer comes up, it shows that a PDF is attached, however after sending, when I check the email, the file is not there.

This is my code that calls it, I've checked to make sure the file path is being set correctly and it appears to be (using the same file that works in child browser somewhere else in the app).

Any suggestions? Also, I'm using cordova 2.1.0

Here's my code that calls the plugin:

```
var strPath = window.location.href; 
var path = encodeURI(strPath.substr(0,strPath.lastIndexOf('/')) + URL); 
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer(subject,body,[],[],[],true,[path]);
```

Here's the EmailComposer code:

```
- (void) showEmailComposer:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [options valueForKey:@"toRecipients"], @"toRecipients",
                                [options valueForKey:@"ccRecipients"], @"ccRecipients",
                                [options valueForKey:@"bccRecipients"], @"bccRecipients",
                                [options valueForKey:@"subject"], @"subject",
                                [options valueForKey:@"body"], @"body",
                                [options valueForKey:@"bIsHTML"], @"bIsHTML",
                                [options valueForKey:@"attachments"], @"attachments",
                                nil];
    [self showEmailComposerWithParameters:parameters];
}

-(void) showEmailComposerWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    // set subject
    @try {
        NSString* subject = [parameters objectForKey:@"subject"];
        if (subject) {
            [mailComposer setSubject:subject];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EmailComposer - Cannot set subject; error: %@", exception);
    }

    // set body
    @try {
        NSString* body = [parameters objectForKey:@"body"];
        BOOL isHTML = [[parameters objectForKey:@"bIsHTML"] boolValue];
        if(body) {
            [mailComposer setMessageBody:body isHTML:isHTML];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EmailComposer - Cannot set body; error: %@", exception);
    }

    // Set recipients
    @try {
        NSArray* toRecipientsArray = [parameters objectForKey:@"toRecipients"];
        if(toRecipientsArray) {
            [mailComposer setToRecipients:toRecipientsArray];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EmailComposer - Cannot set TO recipients; error: %@", exception);
    }

    @try {
        NSArray* ccRecipientsArray = [parameters objectForKey:@"ccRecipients"];
        if(ccRecipientsArray) {
            [mailComposer setCcRecipients:ccRecipientsArray];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EmailComposer - Cannot set CC recipients; error: %@", exception);
    }

    @try {
        NSArray* bccRecipientsArray = [parameters objectForKey:@"bccRecipients"];
        if(bccRecipientsArray) {
            [mailComposer setBccRecipients:bccRecipientsArray];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EmailComposer - Cannot set BCC recipients; error: %@", exception);
    }

    @try {
        int counter = 1;
        NSArray *attachmentPaths = [parameters objectForKey:@"attachments"];
        if (attachmentPaths) {
            for (NSString* path in attachmentPaths) {
                @try {
                    NSLog(@"setting the path: %@", path);
                    if ([path hasSuffix:@".pdf"]) {
                        NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
                        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"attachment%d.pdf", counter]];
                    } else {
                        // supposed image
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
                        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"attachment%d.png", counter]];
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                @catch (NSException *exception) {
                    NSLog(@"Cannot attach file at path %@; error: %@", path, exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EmailComposer - Cannot set attachments; error: %@", exception);
    }

    if (mailComposer != nil) {
        [self.viewController presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self returnWithCode:RETURN_CODE_EMAIL_NOTSENT];
    }
    [mailComposer release];
}
```